# How do I install and setup phpMyAdmin on a LAMP Droplet with Virtual Hosts

Tags: server, webserver, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I am trying to add phpMyAdmin to a droplet/server from Digital Ocean, I am trying to follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial the tutorial is written for Ubuntu 16.04 I run 18.04.

I have currently

- Installed LAMP stack
- Added SSH key
- Enabled HTTPS: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/marketplace/lamp/
- Setup a virtual host: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Besides the above, I have run this in the terminal

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo do-release-upgrade
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade

I am now trying to install **phpMyAdmin** from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial

The problem occurs when I run:

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

It gives me this error:  **Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available**

If I run `sudo phpenmod mbstring`nothing happens.

So I can't get any further with the tutorial

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-install-and-setup-phpmyadmin-on-a-lamp-droplet-with-virtual-hosts) person have/had the same problem as me and one guy reply to him and said:

"If you installed it in a different way or have multiple VirtualHosts, then we might need to do a little adjusting to get it running."

The thing is, [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/marketplace/lamp/) tutorial encouraged me to add VirtualHosts so I did that following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04%20tutorial) tutorial as I also mentioned above, but now I have no idea on how to proceed and install phpMyAdmin on one of the virtual host's websites